# Remove class after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

I'd like to put a timeout function to remove these two classes, but I have no idea how to do that. Can anyone help me how to include a timeout here? Thanks in advance.

```
.done(function(response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            // Set the message text.
            $(formMessages).text('Message sent!');

            // Clear the form.
            $('#name').val('');
            $('#email').val('');
            $('#message').val('');
            //$('#budget').val('');
        })
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

maybe something like...

```
 setTimeout(function(){
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            //....and whatever else you need to do
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: Thank you buddy, that's it. But the text still appears, so I used the "$(formMessages).text(''); " to fix it. like a charm, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `queue` method (https://api.jquery.com/queue/) to queue your function calls in combination with `delay`.

```
$(formMessages)
  .addClass('error')
  .delay(3000)
  .queue(function(next){
    $(this).removeClass('error');
    next();
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular js you can use time function like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
            var myE2 = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#compaignhiglighted' ) );
            myE2.removeClass('compaignhiglighted');
          }, 3000);
```

Answer (score -2):

Using jquery...:

```
$(formMessages)
    .delay(3000) // its like settimeout
    .removeClass('error');
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: `.delay` is *only* like `setTimeout` for events in the jQuery queue of an element. `.removeClass` is never put into the queue, it is executed automatically. [Therefore, it does not work](http://jsfiddle.net/o9n9a74y/)